# Driver Installation for AMD Radeon R9 380X (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, radeon

I'm fairly inexperienced Ubuntu user and was wondering if I need to install the lastest AMD driver for my AMD Radeon R9 380X gfx card. I was going to do some gaming so I want the best performance. Is the stock driver good enough? Thanks.

[My hardware specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXePg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stock open source drivers should be fine for most games. You will only need the proprietary *Pro* version of the drivers if you need some additional features for certain games, such as *Vulkan* or maybe *OpenGL 4.5*.

To see what version of OpenGL is currently supported with what you have installed, you can run `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL core profile version"` in a terminal. The version shown there is the highest level of OpenGL the drivers you're currently using supports.

Comment: Ok thanks. That command gave me "OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.3".